# Text over an image inside a JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jeditorpane

Is there any way to add an image with a text overlaying it in a `JEditorPane`?

The following mark-up that was supposed to work:

```html
<html>
<head>

<div width='150' height='150' style='position: relative;'>
  <img src='img_snow_wide.jpg' style='width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;' />
  <div style='position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);'>
    BLAH
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Does not work when used as the text of the `JEditorPane` (type `"text/html"`).

Comment: Swing  HTML support is not very complete. It only supports HTML 3.2 (I believe).

Comment: @camickr, thanks a lot for that piece of info :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While camickr is (mostly - Swing HTML rendering supports a **sub-set** of HTML 3.2) correct, it is the limited support for CSS letting you down here.

This HTML/CSS works.

```
String html = 
        "<html>"
        + "<body>"
        + "<div style='width: 370px; height: 220px; color: white; "
        + "background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg);'>"
        + "<p style='text-align: center;'>Observatory Silhouette!</p>"
        + "</div>"
        + "</body>"
        + "</html>";
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick, @AndrewThompson! As soon as I get home I'll try out this alternative :D